# OpenSSL support - disabled

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, apache2.4

I recently decided to give php a try and after a day of painstaking installation i finally managed to install php5.6, apache2.4, composer, mysql and laravel framework.

however, i cant seem to access public folder of laravel project (located in apache24/htdocs folder) from my localhost, it saying:
FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 73:
Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()

one would say, that i need to activate openssl extension and i did so. however, despite having the extension, having extension folder properly defined and having extension name uncommented in php.ini file, phpinfo() tells me, that its disabled and i should install it.

note: during laravel installation i was prompted, that i am missing openssl, after uncommenting it in php.ini it was all fine.

Any help?

Comment: Is OpenSSL installed?

Comment: Comments/answer given; keep Googling and good luck with this, up until we know what we're really dealing with here. Question's off-topic btw.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to restart apache so that it can load again the php configuration?

I would suggest after restarting apache to do composer update and composer dump-autoload and see it fixes it

Comment: Questions and suggestions to the OP are comments, not answers/solutions. But.... let's see what the OP has to say about all this. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I just posted it as an answer

Comment: There are many possible reasons why it's failing for them and nobody can offer a definite answer/solution, up until we know which animal(s) we're dealing with here. The OP may not have fully researched this and too many possible reasons / answers may not solve the question. The OP can clarifiy here or in comments under the question.

Comment: Strange. i was about to tell you, that i restarted my pc at least 3 times, but decided to restart apache specifically and it works...
laravel welcoming screen works and so does phpinfo() tells, that openssl is enabled. thanks, mate.

Comment: *"Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment"* - @ggeo and now you do ;-) TBH, sometimes posting as such does lead to a solution and to be honest again, is the reason I didn't "downvote" your answer because you stood to be right about it, and you were.